# How to bind click event to element is created on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
       var button = document.createElement('button');
       $(button).addClass('button');
       $(button).html('Button');
       $(button).appendTo('.container');
    });
});
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgmjohpg/4/)

Buttons is created by button click hasn't click event. How to attach this event to have possibility to create buttons with using of any button?

Comment: Use delegated events ... but if you want to reference the current event handler function, use `arguments.callee` inside the zvznt handler itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [delegate the event handler](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to work with dynamically generated elements.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

You can use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to delegate the handler as follows:

```
$(document).on("click",".button",function() {})
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgmjohpg/5/)